# 12.04 -> 13.10 trouble

Tags: 13.10, system-installation

I had 12.04 running decently, and decided to move to 13.10. When running 13.10 off the usb it's faster than 12.04 was, so I installed it over 12.04. Now that it's installed, it's SLOW. Not "it takes longer to open something" slow, it's "Running at 10 fps slow." Any idea why or how to fix it?

Comment: By "install", do you mean upgrade 12.04 to 13.10 using the built-in upgrade manager or do a fresh install of 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed 12.04 along side 13.10 remove 12.04 if it is not needed then just clean up your system using [BleachBit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/bleachbit/) or any other cleaner (enable deep scan ) it may solve your problem.